# Android 4.0.3 Progress Dialog Closing

Tags: java, android, dialog, progress

On android 4.0.3 apparently the progress dialog closes when you click on the grayed area.
Is there any way to prevent the Progress Dialog from Closing on tap?

> SOLVED-
>
> > PROGRESSDIALOG.setCancelable(false);

Comment: Did you verify this behavior?  It doesn't behave like this on 4.0.2/Galaxy Nexus.

Comment: I tried it on various tablets with the same outcome. I fixed it by using PROGRESSDIALOG.setCancelable(false);

Comment: @ManakKapoor: Please remove the answer from your question and post it as an answer instead!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
_progress.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

prevents the dialog from being closed on tap but still allows the back button to be used.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that can be disabled.
In the XML declaration of the progress bar,set
`android:clickable="false"
 android:focusable="false"
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"`.

Comment: 1. ProgressDialog was called programmatically so i'm not aware how to set those properties.

2. I fixed it using PROGRESSDIALOG.setCancelable(false);

Comment: PROGRESSDIALOG.setCancelable(false);